# Read all the data from the excel

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

I want to read the data from the first row and perform the action, then write the result, then read the second row until there is no more data in the Excel file.

My questions:

- Why don't the iterators work?
- Why doesn't (Selenium's) `driver.findElement` do what it is supposed to?

---

Main program

```
  @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        String sPath = "default.xlsx";
        DataHelper.setExcelFile(sPath, "sheet1");
        XSSFRow row;
        XSSFCell cell;
        boolean flag = true;
        XSSFSheet sheet = ExcelWSheet;
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            List <String> obj = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
               cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
               String cellobj = cell.getStringCellValue();
               if(flag)
               {
                   driver.findElement(By.id("text")).sendKeys(cell);
                   driver.findElement(By.id("text")).click();
                   driver.findElement(By.id("text")).clear;
               }
            }
        }   
    }
```

DataHelper.java

```
public class DataHelper {
    public static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;
    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;
    private static XSSFCell cell;
    private static String path;

    public static void setExcelFile(String path, String SheetName) throws Exception {
        path = path;
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
        ExcelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        ExcelWSheet = ExcelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);

    }
```

}

### Excel data

Email, Password

hello, 123

hello1, 123

Comment: What seems to be the problem here? Did you debug your code? Is the file read correctly? Does the code enter both while loops?

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide the contents of the Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

After a general cleanup (overuse of static etc) the iterators works nicely. See code below.

Regarding the Selenium calls I don't have the knowledge to help. I suggest you post this as two separate questions next time. What I know is that you need to explicitly save the workbook to file if you want to see any changes in the file itselft. I'm suspecting that's what you want. There are plenty of easy-to-find-and-understand examples out there.

```
public void test() throws Exception {
    String sPath = "default.xlsx";
    DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper(sPath, "sheet1");
    XSSFSheet sheet = dataHelper.getExcelWSheet();
    Iterator<Row> rows = sheet.rowIterator();
    while (rows.hasNext()) {
        Row row = rows.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cells = row.cellIterator();
        while (cells.hasNext()) {
            Cell cell = cells.next();
            String cellobj = cell.getStringCellValue();
            if(flag) {
                driver.findElement(By.id("text")).sendKeys(cell);
                driver.findElement(By.id("text")).click();
                driver.findElement(By.id("text")).clear;
            }                
        }
    }
}

public class DataHelper {
    private XSSFSheet excelWSheet;
    private XSSFWorkbook excelWBook;

    public DataHelper(String path, String SheetName) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream ExcelFile = new FileInputStream(path);
        excelWBook = new XSSFWorkbook(ExcelFile);
        excelWSheet = excelWBook.getSheet(SheetName);
    }

    public XSSFSheet getExcelWSheet() {
        return excelWSheet;
    }
}
```